# Delphi 2010 RTTI - how can I get list of indexed properties?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, rtti

With

```
  Cont := TRttiContext.Create;
  for Prop in Cont.GetType(TStrings).GetDeclaredProperties do
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Prop.ToString);
  Cont.Free;
```

I get list of all properties of TStrings except indexed properties (Strings, Values, ...).
As I can see in Get[Declared]Properties are never indexed properties. How can I get indexed properties too?

Comment: RTTI for indexed properties was added in XE2, see [DocWiki section: Working with indexed properties](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Run-Time_Operations_on_Types).

Comment: @LURD - I didn't know / saw. Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.  They aren't included in Delphi 2010's RTTI.

Comment: Well, there's not much more I could say.  I've got some idea as to why, but I couldn't explain it very well.  Barry Kelly probably could.  I wonder if he'll see this question...